# How to grep the pattern within parenthesis?

Tags: regex, grep

Here is the string :

```
Usage:       xp (UUID: 30503c82-bf04-4f75-ab8f-129b8b350487)
```

I want to grep this pattern

```
30503c82-bf04-4f75-ab8f-129b8b350487
```

I can use **grep** and **sed** to pick off it,using like this:

```
grep \(.*\) -o | sed 's/[()]//g'
```

can i use only **grep** to accomplish this opration？

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use

```
egrep 'UUID[^\)]+' -o
```

which will include the "UUID:" prefix that your example code produces.

To get only the id, you can use

```
egrep '[0-9a-f]{8}-([0-9a-f]{4}-){3}[0-9a-f]{12}' -o
```

In action:

```
$ echo 'Usage:       xp (UUID: 30503c82-bf04-4f75-ab8f-129b8b350487)' | egrep '[0-9a-f]{8}-([0-9a-f]{4}-){3}[0-9a-f]{12}' -o
30503c82-bf04-4f75-ab8f-129b8b35
$ echo 'Usage:       xp (UUID: 30503c82-bf04-4f75-ab8f-129b8b350487)' | egrep 'UUID[^\)]+' -o
UUID: 30503c82-bf04-4f75-ab8f-129b8b350487
```